# When I run Spring this error offenly coming? is this version of jar?

Tags: java, spring, jetty

When I run simple spring program, the following error ll display offenly coming.

I am using Tomcat 6 and eclipse Helios.

is this of version problem of jar?

Can you pleased help me

> SEVERE: Servlet /SpringExample5 threw load() exception
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/log/Log

Answer (score 4):

This error has nothing to do with Spring.  Your application is missing the [Jetty 6](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) libraries, and won't run without them.

Comment: A side note is that a no NoClassDefFoundError can imply the class was located but had a static initialization error.